# Is there mitigation for the new NTFS corruption bug?

Tags: ntfs, filesystem-corruption, bug

A recent [announcement of a bug that causes corruption of an NTFS partition](https://www.theverge.com/2021/1/15/22232589/microsoft-ntfs-windows-10-bug-icon-file-flaw-vulnerability-comment) states:

> “…extract the ZIP file or simply look at a folder that contains a malicious shortcut and it will automatically trigger hard drive corruption.”

Further, even entering those few bytes as URL in a browser would also cause NTFS corruption. This issue has also been [confirmed by Bleeping Computer](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/windows-10-bug-corrupts-your-hard-drive-on-seeing-this-files-icon/). Further, though Windows `chkdsk` might sometimes resolve the corruption, if the malicious shortcut still exists, it will trigger corruption *again* as soon as the OS “sees” it in the file system.

- Is there **any** work-around or mitigation of this issue for Windows OS?
- For example, can Windows Registry be modified to handle that location?
- Also, does Linux have that issue when an NTFS partition is mounted, whether read-only or read/write?

If  not, that might be a work-around for those who dual boot.

Comment: A workaround for what, exactly? If you have a malicious shortcut, you can just go and delete that shortcut. Are you saying that triggering this issue actually stops the user from making any changes to the filesystem until a chkdsk run?

Comment: (To be honest I have a strong suspicion that this doesn't actually trigger any corruption at all – it looks like it triggers an internal consistency check which merely *thinks* the filesystem is corrupted because the actual stream type on disk is different than what the user requested. It's a bit like trying to open a directory as if it were a file.)

Comment: @user1686, if you read the articles referenced, simply **having the maliciously constructed shortcut on the system by itself causes corruption**, i.e. damages the file system structure. When the OS accesses the shortcut so that it can (later) be displayed, it searches for the icon, and in doing so causes damage. Admittedly, I have not tried to create that malicious shortcut, but you're welcome to do so on your own (hopefully virtual) machine and report back your findings here.

Comment: I have read them and I have already tried it on my system a while ago, receiving the corruption alert and associated event log messages. I observed that the system did not crash or otherwise malfunction (except for the alert) – I could continue to create or delete files on that disk, in other words, nothing that would prevent you from deleting the shortcut. (And I note that all those articles failed to consider that the alert is may be a false positive – my suspicion is that the bug simply _makes Windows think_ that there is corruption, without actually doing anything to the disk itself.)

Comment: "in a test by BleepingComputer, even after running chkdsk, the operating system would not start properly." https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-ntfs-corruption-bug-gets-unofficial-temporary-fix/

Answer (score 2):

As of Jan 25, 2021, there is a temporary patch for the recently-introduced NTFS bug from [software development company OSR](https://www.osr.com/), while awaiting an official fix from Microsoft.

From [Bleeping Computer:](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-ntfs-corruption-bug-gets-unofficial-temporary-fix/)

> This filter driver, called 'i30Flt', will monitor for attempts to access
> streams beginning with “:$i30:", and if detected, block them before
> they can trigger the bug...

> As Microsoft has told BleepingComputer
> that they plan to fix this bug, once it is patched, you can remove
> the filter driver...

That said, this is an unverified patch from a third party, and one might choose instead to make frequent disk images while awaiting the MS official fix. Or perhaps use another OS.

When that patch is issued, I plan to update this answer.